# In Redux Forms, how do I validate one field based on the value of another?

Tags: validation, reactjs, redux-form

I am using [Redux Form](http://redux-form.com) version 6.4.3 and I'm trying to validate two date fields such that the 'to' date must always be before the 'from' date.

Other examples say I ought to be able to refer to the `fields` array in `props` but there is no such array.  The `form` `state` has an array called `registeredFields` however but those just seem to be of the form `{name: 'dob', type: 'Field'}`

Here is my form code

```
import React      from 'react'
import DatePicker from 'react-bootstrap-date-picker'
import moment     from 'moment'

import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form'
import {Form, Row, Col, Button, FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl, HelpBlock} from 'react-bootstrap'

// validations
const required = value => !value ? 'This field is required' : undefined
const maxDate = max => value =>
  value && moment(value).isAfter(max) ? `Must be before ${max}` : undefined
const minDate = min => value =>
  value && moment(value).isBefore(min) ? `Must be after ${min}` : undefined

const renderDatepicker = ({ input, label, hint, showTodayButton, meta: { pristine, touched, warning, error } }) => {
  const validationState = pristine ? null : error ? 'error' : warning ? 'warning' : null
  return (
  <FormGroup validationState={validationState}>
    <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={3}>{label}</Col>
    <Col sm={3}>
      <FormControl
        {...input}
        componentClass={DatePicker}
        placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
        dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
        showTodayButton={showTodayButton}/>
    </Col>
    {pristine && !!hint && (
      <Col sm={6}>
        <HelpBlock>{hint}</HelpBlock>
      </Col>
    )}
    {touched && (
      (error && (
        <Col sm={6}>
          <HelpBlock>{error}</HelpBlock>
        </Col>)
      ) || (warning && (
        <Col sm={6}>
          <HelpBlock>{warning}</HelpBlock>
        </Col>
      ))
    )}
  </FormGroup>
)}

const MyForm = props => {
  const { error, handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting, fields } = props
  console.debug('fields', fields) // fields is undefined
  return (
    <Form horizontal>
      <Field
        name="dateFrom"
        component={renderDatepicker}
        label="Date from"
        hint="Earliest date for enquiry"
        validate={[required, maxDate('where do I get the other date value from?')]}
      />
      <Field
        name="dateTo"
        component={renderDatepicker}
        label="Date to"
        showTodayButton={true}
        hint="Latest date for enquiry"
        validate={[required, minDate('where do I get the other date value from?')]}
      />
    </Form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'MyForm',
})(MyForm)
```

I get the feeling I am missing something obvious since all the examples I have seen expect that the `fields` array to exist in the `props`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Redux Form, use:

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'MyForm',  // a unique identifier for this form
  validate,                // <--- validation function given to redux-form
})(MyForm)

const validate = values => {
  const errors = {}
  // Here you can get all the fields in value object, use value.min or value.max
  return errors
}
```

http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/syncValidation/

Comment: Awesome. That's exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 9):

It's also worth mentioning that the `Field`'s validate function signature is `validate : (value, allValues, props) => error [optional]` so you actually have a reference to other fields values in field-level validation as well.

I believe you could do something like:

```
const maxDateValidationAdapter = (value, values) => maxDate(values.dateTo)(value);
// Alternatively, if maxDate() is used only in this form you can just change its signature
<Field
    name="dateFrom"
    component={renderDatepicker}
    label="Date from"
    hint="Earliest date for enquiry"
    validate={[required, maxDateValidationAdapter]}
/>
```

See [Field documentation](http://redux-form.com/6.6.1/docs/api/Field.md/) (Props you can pass to Field => validate).

Comment: Keep in mind that passing validators like this (as an inline function) will result in having `Field` unregistered and reregistered on every parent component rerender, which can lead to some unwanted behaviour. It can be observed in actions dispatched by redux-form.

Comment: @crollywood true, 10x for pointing it out. I'll improve the answer.